# P2PKH - Sharing a wallet address does not reveal my pub key?

Tags: address, public-key, signature, p2pkh

Is it technically correct to say that if I share my address with the network, nobody has access to my pubkey still?

But if I share a valid signature to a P2PKH UTXO, someone can derive my pubkey and consequently spend my UTXO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it technically correct to say that if I share my address with the
>   network, nobody has access to my pubkey still?

Yes, if your address is a [standard address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address), then deriving the public key from an address is practically impossible (because it is hashed). But as soon as a transaction is made which spends funds sent to that address, then the public key is in the signature of the spending tx.

A `P2PKH` transaction contains:

```
scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubKeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
scriptSig: <sig> <pubKey>
```

So, once a `P2PKH UTXO` is spent, one can simply look at the script sig for the `pubKey`.

This is because in order to verify transaction [signatures](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG), nodes need the corresponding public key. For this reason, sometimes users will use different addresses for each transaction to help ensure more privacy.